# Random gsub string n-times

Tags: ruby, gsub

How can I randomly replace substring, exactly n-times in Ruby?

For example, I have a text:

> foo foo foo foo bar bar foo bar foo bar

I want to replace two random *foos* with *boo* in any part of string above.

These are the possible results:

1. foo foo boo foo bar bar foo bar boo bar
2. boo foo foo foo bar bar boo bar foo bar
3. foo boo foo boo bar bar foo bar foo bar
4. etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str = "foo foo foo foo bar bar foo bar foo bar"
num = 2
# get an array of all foo's; replace 2 foos with boo; shuffle the array.
ar = (["boo"]*num + str.scan(/foo/)[num..-1]).shuffle
# replace each foo with the next element of the array.
str.gsub(/foo/){ ar.pop }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find all occurrences of the substring you want to replace with `string.index("substring")`. You will get the index of the first character of the substring.

Then you can use the substring after this index to find the next occurrence of the string you want to replace and so on.

Store all the indexes where the substring to replace starts and use a random number to define which of them should be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest one is:

```
str.gsub(/foo/){|v| rand(2) == 0 ? 'boo' : v}
```

Comment: this replaces probabilistically half the 'foo's not only 2 'foo's